# undefined index error with ternary operator PHP

Tags: php, refactoring, ternary-operator

In the code here, i get an **undefined index** error using ternary operator.

**here is the code :**

```
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] 
        : isset($_GET['phone'])? $_GET['phone'] : null;
```

But, the posted array has the `phone` index as shown in the image(captured from VS Code ).

[image]

When I changed it to this,

```
if(isset($_POST['phone']))$phone =  $_POST['phone'];
else $phone = isset($_GET['phone']) ? $_GET['phone'] : null;
```

The code works fine. is it any error in my code? or is it not supported in ternary operator?

Comment: try wrapping the 'false' -> `$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone']  : (isset($_GET['phone'])? $_GET['phone'] : null);`